# How to generate c/c++ function prototypes automatically?

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, ide

It's annoying to have to type a function prototypes twice> Is there an IDE that does this automatically?

For example, how to do this in Eclipse with CDT?

Basically I am asking for 3 things:

1. Generate prototypes for defined functions.
2. Generate function snippets for declared prototypes.
3. If anything changes to the argument types in either the prototype or the definition, keep them in sync.

Comment: If you're typing the *same* function twice, you're doing something wrong!

Comment: When you define private methods within your .c file, you need to create local function prototypes for forward references within the file.  (You don't want them in the .h file.)  I'd love a way to automate the creation of those prototypes.

Answer (score 1):

> For example, how to do this in Eclipse with CDT?

If you already declared your prototypes in a header file, choose from there with the context menu **'Source->Implement Method...'**. This will popup a dialog to let you select which unimplemented methods should be generated in the corresponding source.

Comment: How about the other way around, if I have defined the functions, can it generate prototypes for me?

Comment: @qed AFAIK no! But starting with the declarations is the most usual approach anyway IMHO.